# How do I supply file path that is the same as the path in the gallery when taking photo in Android?

Tags: android

I tried to take a picture using camera intent and want to get the file path of the full size image. I am following the tutorial from http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html. The problem, when I look into the file path in `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` column using `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`, the image have different path. How do I supply the same file path? I looked at [taking a photo and placing it in the Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866108/taking-a-photo-and-placing-it-in-the-gallery), I though it is simply just change `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` to `Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM`, but it still didn't work.

Below is my code for taking photo.

```
private Uri photoPath;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(photoPath, null);
            System.out.println(photoPath);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.getId() == R.id.camera_button) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        try {
            String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String image = "IMG_" + timestamp;
            File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            File photo = File.createTempFile(image, ".jpg", storageDir);
            photoPath = Uri.fromFile(photo);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoPath);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

my code above produce file path `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20150805_121624.jpg` while it is actually `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100MEDIA/IMAG0531.jpg` in the gallery. the former path is really my image (as I specified it on `photoPath`), but I want to get the later path instead. How could I do that?

Comment: Can you show some code snippets? The question is not much clear.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM`.

The android API DOC clearly has the details of various directories which can be used. 
I hope this will help you to save your file to `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/`.

Comment: I've tried that and the result, my image path would be something like `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/IMG_20150805_121624.jpg`, and still miss the `100MEDIA` part. If I put it manually, I'm afraid it would be different in another phone.

Comment: Looks like it is manufacturer dependent. In addition to using methods described in book, it seems also allowing the user to choose/override the default you "discover" would be an important option.

From Pro Android 3: p 579

Unfortunately, there is not a method call to tell you which directory might be used underneath the DCIM directory for Camera pictures. There are a couple of methods though to tell you where the top of the SD card is. The first is Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() and it returns a File object for the top-level directory for the SD card.